# Manually Adding JAR files in Maven or Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, offline

I am developing a Spring Boot project on Office LAPTOP by using Eclipse.

Due to the firewall restriction the Springframework jar files cannot be downloaded into when I update the pom.xml.

Is there any way I can add the required Spring Boot Framework jar files manually ?

For example can I copy the entire .m2/repository folder from another system that is connected to internet and had automatically downloaded all the jar files ?

Or what is the best approach to load the .jar file in Offline mode (without Internet connectivity)

Comment: Option1: There are always proxies used in Organizations. Ask someone about that and add the relevant information in settings.xml
Option2: Manually copy the JARS in M2. It will not fail. If find in m2.  it looks the dependencies in local m2 first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

on a computer with internet access.

Then copy the .m2/repository to your office computer.

Maven also have a flag -o to tell maven that it must run offline. For example:

```
mvn -o verify
```

Please find more information about the offline mode here. https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html#running-sect-offline-option